bluetooth connection in Ubuntu24.4
I have installed Ubuntu 24.4 and ever since I`ve got problem with bluetooth connection.
I have to connect my keyboard to laptop via Bluetooth, but it keeps get disconnected. Also, my headphones are not connected to it at all.
I appreciate any hint on this matter.
BTW, I have already tried solutions provided on the similar questions for earlier versions of Ubuntu.
